# How different is NodeJs Architecture?

Tags: node.js

Have some questions regarding NodeJs Architecture:

1. It says although NodeJs is single threaded, internally it uses libuv library's thread pool? Is it right?
2. All non-blocking requests handled by main thread and all blocking requests handled by libuv thread pool? While some says there is nothing like main thread. Right or misconception?
3. If yes, then what happen if thread pool size is 4 and blocking requests are 
   Request no 5 have to be wait until thread is available? Is it right?
4. if point 3 is the case, then how NodeJs is different from Java if blocking requests count exceeds thread pool size?

Answer (score 0):

1.
In general, both `libuv` and `v8` are allowed to use (and in fact use) threads.
As a rule of thumb, note that a single threaded JavaScript runtime environment doesn't mean that the underlying libraries cannot use threads.

2.
You can refer to the [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html) of `libuv` to know what will be dispatched on threads.
I cite it:

- File system operations
- DNS functions
- User specified code via uv_queue_work()

3.
It is said that you can *queue work on* the thread pool.
So, yes, if you queue more work that what you can schedule, requests are going to wait their turn to run.

4.
A thread pool is a concept that abstracts away from the language.
At the end of the day, `libuv` and thus node are well targeted for I/O bound applications where you do a lot of networking and the API clearly states it.